# Supremum of two subtracted fractions less than one

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $$S=\left\{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}: m,n∈\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

Find the Supremum of this set.
I get the feeling that the answer is $1$ as if you let $n=1$ and $m$ be infinitely large then its $1-\text{something infinitely small}$, but I'm not sure how to prove this?

Comment: Use the definition of the supremum: Obviously $1$ is an upper bound for this set, but why is it the smallest?

Comment: What if you rewrite the terms as $$\frac{m-n}{mn}?$$ Is $mn$ always larger than $m-n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $1$ is an upper bound as if $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then  $0<\frac{1}{n}\le 1$.

Let $p$ is a real number satisfying $p<1$ then, we shall prove that $p$ is not an upper bound.

As $1-p>0$ archimededan property of $\mathbb{R}$ guarantees that there exists an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m(1-p)>1\Rightarrow 1-p>\frac{1}{m}\Rightarrow 1-\frac{1}{m}>p$. As $1-\frac{1}{m}\in S$ , this proves that $p$ is not an upper bound.

We have shown that $1$ satisfies the two conditions of supremum and hence it is the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}<1$.

Suppose  $\sup(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m})=K<1$ and obtain a contradiction:

Let $n=1$ and show that $1-\frac{1}{m}>K$ for some $m$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$ and $m>1/\varepsilon$ then $\dfrac 1n -\dfrac 1 m>1-\varepsilon$.

So for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a member of this set bigger than $1-\varepsilon$, but there is no member as big as $1$.